# File name on matlab script editor window title in detached mode

Tags: linux, windows, macos, matlab, macos-high-sierra

I prefer to code in Matlab script editor using it detached from the main window. Below you can see just the script window:

[image]

The window title shows the file full path. Is it possible to show just the filename? How?

Side question: How can I know which file is being edited?

Comment: https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/about-editor-debugger-preferences.html ?

Comment: It seems there is no way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top bar displays the complete path which is actually a useful feature in my opinion. You cannot have only the filename in the *detached editor* unless by modifying the underlying Java (which will very likely breach ***MathWorks Software License Agreement***).

Only tabs show just the filename in the *main editor* (not detached editor). If your tabs are hidden in the main editor, you can fix that by:

> View → Tab Position → Top (or any other position as per your choice)

---

When a file is being edited (and not saved yet), an asterisk (`*`) appears next to it on both its tab and the top bar.

Comment: Is this option in Matlap Preferences? Or should I look for it in the detached editor view tab? Can't find Tab Position anywhere.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what you meant by *detached editor*. That  option is available in the main editor window, not in the *detached one*.

Comment: When in the main editor, click and drag the tab outside the main window, you have what I call script editor in a detached window. BTW I found the option.

Comment: Btw why do you want to detach it?

Comment: I don't need to see all matlab environment while coding. There other things to see, like browser.

Comment: Oh well, it seems that your editor is docked and all you need is to undock it instead of detaching. Click on circled `▾` symbol on the top right in the undetached editor and then select undock.

Comment: No. It's already undocked. The problem seems to be that `Tabs Position` default option is `Hide`, changing it to `Top` helps. Please mention in your answer that the option is only available when in docked mode and I'll check it as correct.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your last comment.  Actually `Tab Position` is not dependent on whether the editor is docked or undocked. It is available/modifiable in both the cases